# What is the correct SMPP error code to indicate corrupt/invalid UDH field values?

Tags: smpp

I'm trying to handle UDH data for multipart messages and I want to use an appropriate error code when there's a problem with the multipart fields.  There are several error codes for bad TLV's, but I don't see anything except generic failure messages that I could use for UDH.  Is that the best I can do here, or is there a more direct message I could use?

Answer (score 0):

Your observation is correct - there is not a single error defined for UDH.

If you want, you can use error codes from reserved section and assign specific meaning to one/some of them. I think the "Reserved for SMSC vendor specific errors" (0x400-0x4FF) can be a good candidate.

Comment: Yeah I saw that.   I was hoping there was some convention that wouldn't require peers to know my custom error code.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it looks to me like `ESME_RX_R_APPN = 0x66` "ESME receiver reject message error." is the best error code to throw here.

It should correspond to a permanent error *for this message only* and let further messages be processed.